# Why is "showData()" not printing my arrays value when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, json, oop

sorry for this very specific question. I want to coda a simple Shopping-Cart App for me and my girlfriend. For storing the Data I thought of using a .JSON-File. I tried OOP the first time and it went pretty well. But now I am stuck.

My UI.showData() should print all the data of my items-array to my page. When I used a for(let i=0; i<items.length; I++)-loop the data was shown, but it added all items when clicking my button. So not just "milk" as the new user-input but "milk", "beer", "cheese" and so on.

At the moment my data is only stored in an array. I didn't start saving to JSON. As I am new in the world of coding I am happy with every advice even if it's "off-topic" (like my overall style of coding in this case).

In addition I was struggling with the choice of using a .JSON-File or a Database - so if you have any advices/pro-con's I would like to hear. I decided for .JSON because it is a small and unnecessary amount of data in the case of our Shopping-Card.

Here is my Javascript-Code:

```js
// Preparation:

const input = document.getElementById('input');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

let count = 0;
let items = [];


// UI-Tasks:

class UI {

    //Display the array:
    
    static showData(arr){

        arr.forEach(item => UI.createElement(item));

    };

    //Add data to the DOM:
    
    static createElement(item){

        let newItem = document.createElement('div');
        let newDelete = document.createElement('button');

        //Add Class and innerHTML:
        newItem.classList.add('item');
        newItem.innerHTML = item.prod;

        //Add Delete-Button:
        newDelete.classList.add('delete');
        newDelete.innerHTML = 'x';

        //Append to "container":
        newItem.appendChild(newDelete);
        container.appendChild(newItem);

    };

    static deleteBook(e){
        
    }

    //Clear the Input-Forms:
    static clearInput(){

        input.value = '';

    };

    //

};

// Data-Handling:

class Functionality {

    static addUserInput(){

        let userInput = input.value;

        const newObj = {id:count,prod:userInput};
        items.push(newObj);

        //UI.createElement(newObj);
    };

};

btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    Functionality.addUserInput();
    UI.clearInput();
    
    count++;
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.showData(items));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Einkaufsliste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2 id="heading">Einkaufsliste</h2>
        <h4>von * & *</h4>
    </header>

    <main>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="product">Was wird gebraucht?</label><br>
            <input id="input" name="product" type="text">

            <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Hinzufügen">
        </form>


    </main>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: small note on modern JS: just add your script to the `<head>` element and add the `async` and `defer` attributes so that it loads non-blocking and executes automatically when the document has been parsed. That way you also don't need `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded...` anymore: you are _guaranteed_ that the document is ready for queries when the script runs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! So the script runs when the HTML finished loading?

Comment: Yep, that's what [the `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) is for - it got added once it became obvious everyone was using jQuery to wait for the DOM to be ready =)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the event listeners return value and not the listener itself.
It should be:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => UI.showData(items));
```

Also items are just an empty array when the script runs so it wont render anything.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, that's kind of stupid.. if I add dummy objects to my array they will be shown. So if I add UI.createElement(newObj) to my Functionality.addUserInput() Method I get the user input as a new div. Is there a way to loop over the array again without refreshing the page? Or should I just store my data in the .JSON-File and refresh the page after submitting?

Comment: JavaScript is stateless. If you refresh the page the data is gone unless you have stored it using a backend, cookies or local storage. If you want to to append a new item to dom just call UI.createElement for this item and add id to items page. Then you can try to store items array in local storage and update it each time it is written and on pageload you read local storage if it exists to get saved items.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will continue with saving my data on local storage!

Comment: but also remember to upvote and accept things =)